# Android NFC Locks up / Stops Scanning after Repetative Scans

Tags: android, barcode-scanner, nfc, nexus-s

**Overview**:
We have developed an app that allows customers check in using an NFC enabled card with a stationary Nexus S. The app sit ready to read a card, when a card is tapped, the app reads the unique ID for the NFC card.

**Problem**:
The challenge we have run into, is that the Nexus S locks up after scanning 50 to 100 tags. The app continues to function, and so does android, however neither our app, or the native app within android will read a tag. It is as though the scanner has been disabled. I have tested it using 4 different Nexus S devices running Android 2.3.6.

**Debugging**:
The only solution I have been able to find is to either:
- power the nexus s off and then power it back on
- disable NFC and then re-enable it through Setting --> Wireless & network settings --> NFC

If either of those are done, the scanner works again and app continues to work as normal until it locks up again after 70 or so scans.

Any idea how to fix this bug, or work around the issue?

**Update:** it appears as though this is not just with our app, testing the "Tags" native app that comes with the Nexus S also has this issue.

Comment: I've experienced the same thing as well, scanning a wide variety of tags.

Comment: Same problem here, but it happens after only about 10 scans.

Comment: It's not possible programatically without rooting device. But you can start NFC Settings Activity by intent action Settings.ACTION_NFC_SETTINGS for api level 16 and above. For api < 16 use Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS

Answer (score 2):

We have experienced the same issue with our NFC apps. Seems to be a hardware issue. We have done the same thing you are doing by re-enabling NFC in settings.

Unfortunately I don't think it's your problem so you may have to report the issue directly to Samsung or Google via Samsung Tech Support or a Google Android bug report.

Another thing to do is to see how the tag recognition works with the new Galaxy Nexus when it gets released in the next 2 weeks.